# What's the verb for 'to confer the title of Dame upon'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

If a man becomes a Knight, he does so by being *knighted*.

What word describes the action by which one confers the title of Dame upon a woman?

Is she *damed*? Or *knighted*? Or something else?

Comment: As far as I can tell, they are just “***made a dame***”. No special verb is used.

Comment: They are _deemed a dame_, by someone with the authority to deem them so. Then they don't need to be redeemed.

Comment: If she is introduced into the Order of the Bath, she is, of course, [_bathed_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Bath). This would seem to entail somewhat more exposure than being [_gartered_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Garter), but to be significantly less uncomfortable than being [_thistled_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Thistle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent verb to "to knight" for a  Dame. You need to use expressions like to honour someone with the title of Dame or do make someone a Dame:

Dame:

> - a woman's name that is given in Britain as a special honour, usually for valuable work done over a long period, or a woman having this honour:
>
>   - *Dame Judy Dench.*
>   - *She was made a dame before she died.*

***[Honour](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/honour)*** (someone)  with (something):

> - To give someone public praise or a reward:
>
>   - *He was honoured with a knighthood.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Yes, she's *honoured with a Damehood*, but *honour* by itself doesn't imply the specific title of Dame. A man is simply *knighted*. I was wondering if there's an equivalent to *knight* as a verb, and one that implicitly includes the title of Dame.

Comment: No there is not: ***Dame***  - a woman's name that is given in Britain as a special honour, usually for valuable work done over a long period, or a woman having this honour: - 
*Dame Judy Dench - She was made a dame before she died.*

Comment: @Josh61 - Jud***i*** Dench. And last I checked she was still alive. Wikipedia doesn't record her as dead either.

Comment: @AntyT - the two sencences are not related.

Answer (score 1):

**"dub"** seems to fit perfectly. (to dub someone a Knight or a Dame)

> - [**dub**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dub) (verb, transitive) - To honor with a new title or description,  to invest with a title, name, or nickname [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dub)
> - [**"Dame"**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dame) - (In the UK) the title given to a woman with the rank of Knight Commander or holder of the Grand Cross in the Orders of Chivalry:

- Elizabeth Taylor **was dubbed Dame Elizabeth** by Queen Elizabeth II in 1999.
- In 1913 **he was dubbed knight** by King George V.

Comment: Yes, she's *dubbed a Dame*, but she isn't simply *dubbed*. A man isn't *knighted a Knight*, he's simply *knighted*. I was wondering if there's an equivalent to *knight* as a verb, and one that implicitly includes the title of Dame.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with the other answers that say there is no word that intrinsically means "be made into a Dame", but the word ***ennoble*** does include damehood as a possibility:

> 2:  to raise to the rank of nobility
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ennoble)*</sub>